# OctoberCMS: Why is the slug value missing in "post.url" of the blog plugin

Tags: php, octobercms

I am using the `[blogPosts]` component of the blog plugin. I have a for loop to display all blog posts. Everything is fine, but the value of `{{ post.url }}` is missing the slug value. This is how I have used the component:

```
url = "/blog/:page?"
layout = "default"

[blogPosts]
pageNumber = "{{ :page }}"
postsPerPage = 10
noPostsMessage = "No posts found"
sortOrder = "published_at desc"
categoryPage = 404
postPage = "post"
==
{% set posts = blogPosts.posts %}
{% for post in posts %}
<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ post.summary|raw }}</p>
<a href="{{ post.url }}">Read more</a>
{% endfor %}
```

In the above examples, all post links are referring to `blog/post`.  I expect the `slug` of each post to be in its url, but it's missing. Why?

Comment: can you please share your `post` page details

Comment: The url of the blog post page was `url = "/blog/post"`. I changed it to `url = "/blog/post/:slug"` and the issue was resolved. I didn't know that the url of the post page affects the urls generated in the blog page, that's weird!

Comment: yes it has to include `:slug` to be able to place slug of post in place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it may be an issue with the `blog page URL`.

if you are using `[blogPosts]` and in markup, you need to generate a link of `blog page` using `{{ post.url }}` you need to make proper `url` of the `blog page`

```
title = "Blog Post Page"
url = "/blog/post/:slug"
layout = "default"
is_hidden = 0
==
<?PHP
  // ... other code
```

Here important stuff is `url = "/blog/post/:slug"` and main important thing is `:slug` parameter

> URL has to have `:slug` parameter to replace with actual `post slug`.

If you also need to add post category slug in URL then you also need to use `:category` parameter in URL for ex: `url = "/blog/post/:category/:slug"`

> these `:slug` and `:category` is hardcoded in making a link of the post so you need to use exactly them not other `names`. check below screenshot of `post model` from rainlab.post plugin.

[image: post model]

if any doubt please comment.